# Need help in creating XSLT, i do have Source and Target XML

Tags: xml, xslt

I am trying to write XSLT document for the source XML and i do have Traget XML too (what it should look like)

My Source looks like:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
 <soap:Body>
<a xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/directory/">
  <b>
    <c>
      <d>
        <e MemberID="1" />
        <e MemberID="2" />
        <e MemberID="3" />
       </d>
    </c>
  </b>
</a>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

What i want to achieve is (Target XML)

```
<d>
   <e ID="1" />
   <e ID="2" />
   <e ID="3" />
</d>
```

I have been trying to write my XSLT but couldn't get it working. I have been using some online tools, where i give my source and write XSLT but i am not getting any result. (never worked in XSLT)

Can someone please help me in writing this or point me in write direction.

What i have tried is:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="a/b/c/d"/>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="d">
<d>
  <xsl:for-each select="e">
    <e>
          <xsl:value-of select="@MemberID"/> -- I know its wrong, but just want something to work                  
    </e>
  </xsl:for-each>
</d>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Thanks

Comment: Why does your stylesheet include a literal `<Members>` element, when your required output does not? -- P.S. The main issue with your attempt is that you are ignoring the **namespaces** of the source document.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to assign a prefix to each namespace used by the source document, and use the appropriate prefix when addressing elements in the source document. Here's a correction of your stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
xmlns:dir="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/directory/"
exclude-result-prefixes="soap dir">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="soap:Envelope/soap:Body/dir:a/dir:b/dir:c/dir:d"/>
</xsl:template> 

<xsl:template match="dir:d">    
    <d>
        <xsl:for-each select="dir:e">
            <e>
                <xsl:value-of select="@MemberID"/>                 
            </e>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </d>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This will produce the following result :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<d>
  <e>1</e>
  <e>2</e>
  <e>3</e>
</d>
```

Of course, you could simplify this to:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
xmlns:dir="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/directory/"
exclude-result-prefixes="soap dir">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <d>
        <xsl:for-each select="soap:Envelope/soap:Body/dir:a/dir:b/dir:c/dir:d/dir:e">
            <e>
                <xsl:value-of select="@MemberID"/>                 
            </e>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </d>
</xsl:template> 

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

To achieve the required output, change:

```
            <e>
                <xsl:value-of select="@MemberID"/>                 
            </e>
```

to:

```
            <e ID="{@MemberID}"/>
```