# XSLT not displaying SOAP response correctly

Tags: php, xml, xslt, soap

I'm trying to display the result from the soap response into a table using XSLT but i'm getting a blank table.
Here's the screenshot:

[image]

The reponse is not empty. I echoed it for you to see:

[image]

Here's my codes for the client.php:

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['search_input']))
{
try
{
    $input = $_POST['search_input'];

    $wsdl = "http://localhost/WebService/UDDI/90210Store.wsdl";

    //$options = array('cache_wsdl'=>WSDL_CACHE_NONE, 'features'=>SOAP_SINGLE_ELEMENT_ARRAYS);

    //$client = new SoapClient($wsdl, $options);

    $debugOption = array('trace'=>true, 'cache_wsdl'=>WSDL_CACHE_NONE, 'features'=>SOAP_SINGLE_ELEMENT_ARRAYS);
    $client = new SoapClient($wsdl, $debugOption);

    $response = $client->viewDressPerPrice($input);

    /*$res = var_dump($response);
    echo $res;*/

    $soaprequest = "<strong>REQUEST:</strong><br/>" . $client->__getLastRequest() . "<br/>";
    $soapresponse = $client->__getLastResponse();

    echo $soapresponse;

    //$decode = html_entity_decode($soapresponse);

    //echo $decode;

    if(isset($response->DressPerPrice))
    {
        $XMLDocument = simplexml_load_string($soapresponse);    
        $XSLDocument = new DOMDocument();
        $XSLDocument->load("WSEx1.xsl");
        $XSLProcessor = new XSLTProcessor();//PHP5
        $XSLProcessor->importStylesheet($XSLDocument);

       echo $XSLProcessor->transformToXML($XMLDocument);
    }

    else
    {
        echo "This field is not found in database";
    }
}

catch(Exception $e)
{
echo 'Exception: '.$e->getMessage();
}

catch(SOAPFault $exception)
{
echo 'SOAP Exception: '.$exception->getMessage();
}

}

else
{
header("Location: http://localhost/WebService/Client/Category.html");
}

?>
```

This is my xslt file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:strip-space elements="*" /> 
<xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
        <head><title>Web Service</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="WSEx1.css"/>
        </head>
        <body>
            <h3>Dresses Per Price</h3>
            <table border="1">
                <thead>
                    <tr style="background-color:PaleGreen;"><th>Name</th><th>Price</th><th>Image</th></tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <xsl:for-each select="Result">
                        <xsl:apply-templates>
                            <xsl:sort select="Price" data-type="text" order="ascending"/>
                        </xsl:apply-templates>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </tbody>
            </table>
            <p><strong>Note:</strong>Data listed above may not reflect the current state at CSE.</p>
        </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="DressPerPrice">
    <xsl:variable name="cssClass">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="position() mod 2 = 0">coloured</xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>normal</xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:variable>
    <tr class="{$cssClass}">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="Name"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="Price"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="Image"/>
    </tr>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="DressPerPrice|Name|Price">
    <td><xsl:value-of select="text()"/></td>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This is the soap response:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="http://www.shehzad.edu/webservice">
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
    <ns1:Result>
      <ns1:DressPerPrice>
            <ns1:Name>Dress 2</ns1:Name>
            <ns1:Price>20</ns1:Price>
            <ns1:Image>2.jpeg</ns1:Image>
      </ns1:DressPerPrice>
      <ns1:DressPerPrice>
            <ns1:Name>Dress 9</ns1:Name>
            <ns1:Price>20</ns1:Price>
            <ns1:Image>3.jpeg</ns1:Image>
      </ns1:DressPerPrice>
      <ns1:DressPerPrice>
            <ns1:Name>Dress 10</ns1:Name>
            <ns1:Price>20</ns1:Price>
            <ns1:Image>0905C58A0179_1.jpeg</ns1:Image>
      </ns1:DressPerPrice>
      <ns1:DressPerPrice>
            <ns1:Name>Dress 11</ns1:Name>
            <ns1:Price>20</ns1:Price>
            <ns1:Image>0905C58A0179_1.jpeg</ns1:Image>
      </ns1:DressPerPrice>
      <ns1:DressPerPrice>
            <ns1:Name>Dress 12</ns1:Name>
            <ns1:Price>20</ns1:Price>
            <ns1:Image>0905C58A0179_1.jpeg</ns1:Image>
       </ns1:DressPerPrice>
    </ns1:Result>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Is my XSLT wrong? Please help.

Comment: We really need to see the XML code to which you are applying this transformation.

Comment: I edited the question to add the soap response.

Comment: May be you meant to write `<xsl:for-each select="Result/DressPerPrice">` ?

Comment: @mrun I modified it but it is still giving me the same output.

Comment: Before everything, you have a namespace issue. See, for example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26085859/need-help-in-creating-xslt-i-do-have-source-and-target-xml/26086154#26086154

Comment: @michael.hor257k I fixed it. Can you tell me what more has to be changed?

Comment: I am sorry: you fixed what? I see no change in your question.