# xslt Identity Transform Template Failing to Match

Tags: xml, templates, xslt

I need to replace a single data point inside of an xml document with a different text value while keeping the xml document exactly the same.  Whenever the document has a `<Cd>` element value of "SACC" I need to convert it to "SVGS". There are many examples on this site using the identity transform to copy the xml document while applying additional templates to manipulate nodes. I've attempted to replicate these scripts but have been unable to successfully call my 2nd template and replace "SACC" with "SVGS". I think this should be easy since both the value I need to replace and the input value are static. Here is my xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Document xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.001.001.03">
    <CstmrCdtTrfInitn>
        <PmtInf>
            <DbtrAcct>
                <Tp>
                    <Cd>SACC</Cd>
                </Tp>
                <Ccy>JPY</Ccy>
                <Nm>Company</Nm>
            </DbtrAcct>
            <CdtTrfTxInf>
                <CdtrAcct>
                    <Tp>
                        <Cd>SACC</Cd>
                    </Tp>
                    <Ccy>JPY</Ccy>
                    <Nm>Person Name</Nm>
                </CdtrAcct>
            </CdtTrfTxInf>
        </PmtInf>
    </CstmrCdtTrfInitn>
</Document>
```

I am specifically trying to replace the 2nd "SACC" value contained in `<CdtTrfTxInf/CdtrAcct/Tp/Cd>` only while leaving the 1st "SACC" value unchanged. This is my desired xml output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Document xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.001.001.03">
    <CstmrCdtTrfInitn>
        <PmtInf>
            <DbtrAcct>
                <Tp>
                    <Cd>SACC</Cd>
                </Tp>
                <Ccy>JPY</Ccy>
                <Nm>Company</Nm>
            </DbtrAcct>
            <CdtTrfTxInf>
                <CdtrAcct>
                    <Tp>
                        <Cd>SVGS</Cd>
                    </Tp>
                    <Ccy>JPY</Ccy>
                    <Nm>Person Name</Nm>
                </CdtrAcct>
            </CdtTrfTxInf>
        </PmtInf>
    </CstmrCdtTrfInitn>
</Document>
```

Here is the xslt I have created so far that is not working. The identity transform copies the original xml document, but the template to replace the text value is not doing anything. The result is that I end up with an exact, unchanged copy of my original xml document. I have also attempted to match without the "*" wildcard character in my match expression and expressions without the text() argument but still have the same output. Suggestions on why my xpath is not matching or new approaches entirely will be greatly appreciated. Also, it is critical that the spaces and whitespaces of the xml document are undisturbed as the final output will be used for transmitting xml to financial institutions that are remarkably inflexible with the formats they accept. Thanks in advance.

XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="2.0">


    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>  
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*/CdtrAcct/Tp/Cd/text()[.='SACC']">SVGS</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: This is a *namespace* issue - see here how to solve it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26085859/need-help-in-creating-xslt-i-do-have-source-and-target-xml/26086154#26086154

Comment: Thank you for the feedback Michael. I took at a look at the link you posted it covers the namespace issue well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using an XSLT 2.0 processor the you can fix your stylesheet by putting `xpath-default-namespace="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.001.001.03"` on your `xsl:stylesheet` element.

Comment: Thanks Martin! This did the trick. I didn't realize that namespace could come in to play here since the identity-transform was working.  One more question for you, is it possible to have more than 1 default namespace added. I tried to add a 2nd but received error messages from my processor. The 001.001.03 piece refers to the format of the final document and there is a chance that this transformation will be working with either 001.001.03 or 001.001.02. Any more suggestions?