# Is it possible to select an XML namespace using XPATH if you don't know what that namespace represents?

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xslt-1.0

I have some XML data that is using a namespace. I don't know what that namespace represents. To add it to my XSL template it looks like it requires a URL that probably defines the namespace in someway. Is it possible to parse this without know the url for the definition? Can I manually create it?

Here is some same data:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ns:NODE>
  <ns:SUBNODE>
    <ns:VALUE>test</ns:VALUE>
  </ns:SUBNODE>
</ns:NODE>
```

I'm trying to get the value of ns:VALUE but having no luck (I just gave the namespace the xsl tranformation URL hoping it might work):

```
<xsl:template match="/" xmlns:ns="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <document>
      <content name="testing">
        <xsl:value-of select="/ns:NODE/ns:SUBNODE/ns:VALUE" />
      </content>
    </document>
  </vce>
</xsl:template>
```

I was able to get the value using this but I'm guessing this is going to be less performant:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <document>
      <content name="testing">
        <xsl:value-of select="//*[name() = 'ns:VALUE']" /> 
      </content>
    </document>
  </vce>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: That "sample data" isn't valid XML. Do you actually have a parser that claims otherwise?

Comment: Please show your sample input _exactly_ as it is, and I hope it includes a namespace declaration (`xmlns:ns="..."`). If it does not, you cannot use it as input for an XSLT transformation. It is unclear what you mean by "not knowing what the namespace represents".

Comment: Sorry I can't share the exact data as it's sensitive. However, it does not include any namespace declaration just the opening xml tag. Our parser will parse it by default though and just dump all of the nodes inside of one content node. Why are you saying it's not valid XML?

Comment: If your XML uses a prefix without binding the prefix to a namespace URI (in the form of `xmlns:ns="htpp://something.com"`) then it's not XML and cannot be processed by XSLT.

Comment: I looked at the source data and not the output from our conversion process. It looks like the namespace was stripped before the output I first received. It does include the namespace.

Comment: If it does declare the namespace, and that namespace is known to you in advance, proceed as explained here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26085859/need-help-in-creating-xslt-i-do-have-source-and-target-xml/26086154#26086154

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Sorry I can't share the exact data as it's sensitive. However, it **does not include any namespace declaration** just the opening xml tag.

A document that includes namespaces elements, as in

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ns:NODE>
  <ns:SUBNODE>
    <ns:VALUE>test</ns:VALUE>
  </ns:SUBNODE>
</ns:NODE>
```

*must* include a namespace declaration, preferably on the outermost element:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ns:NODE xmlns:ns="www.example.com">
  <ns:SUBNODE>
    <ns:VALUE>test</ns:VALUE>
  </ns:SUBNODE>
</ns:NODE>
```

If it doesn't, your input data does not qualify as XML (i.e. is malformed). An XSLT stylesheet only accepts *well-formed* XML as the input for any transformation.

Comment: Mathias is correct. I was looking at the document after some transformation was applied which must have been stripping the namespace. Looking at the source file I was able to find the namespace and add it using the xmlns attribute.