# Namespaces in XML Root Element Not Work with xsltproc

Tags: xml, xslt, namespaces

I am trying to produce an `html` from an `xml + xslt` by using `xsltproc`.
The `XML` comes in the form:

```
<ResponseData xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Service.Data" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<title>pippo</title>
</ResponseData>
```

And `my.xslt` is as simple as:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
     <body>
      <xsl:value-of select="/title"/>
     <body>
    </html>
```

If I run:

```
xslproc my.xslt my.xml
```

the result is empty.

Strangely, if I remove the `xmlns` attribute, the transformation works and I get the title (pippo).
Why?

Comment: This is a very frequently asked question; see, for example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26085859/need-help-in-creating-xslt-i-do-have-source-and-target-xml/26086154#26086154

Comment: This is not "strange" but expected behaviour. Read about XML namespaces.