# Convert one element in XML tree to another value, inside namespaces via XSLT

Tags: xslt, saml-2.0

I'm trying to manipulate a SAML response (after validation).

The SP is trying to make use of /saml:Assertion/saml:Subject/saml:NameID/content but instead I want it to use /saml:Assertion/saml:AttributeStatement/saml:Attribute/saml:AttributeValue/content where Name is "uid".  (The reason is that the unique identifier is part of the back end attribute and not expressed as the subject, which was a created name.)

That is, inside the SAML response,

```
<saml:Subject>
  <saml:NameID SPNameQualifier="https://10.19.31.141:9443/sps/SimpleSAML/saml20" Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:persistent">4202cf15bef783f0e85a9395eca2dc67020ed333</saml:NameID>
  <saml:SubjectConfirmation Method="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:cm:bearer">
    <saml:SubjectConfirmationData NotOnOrAfter="2015-07-02T13:12:06Z" Recipient="https://10.19.31.141:9443/sps/SimpleSAML/saml20/login" InResponseTo="FIMREQ_4ee0b1eb-014e-1f6b-987d-b8d22c8d5967"/>
  </saml:SubjectConfirmation>
</saml:Subject>
```

needs conversion to

```
<saml:Subject>
  <saml:NameID SPNameQualifier="https://10.19.31.141:9443/sps/SimpleSAML/saml20" Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:persistent">test</saml:NameID>
  <saml:SubjectConfirmation Method="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:cm:bearer">
    <saml:SubjectConfirmationData NotOnOrAfter="2015-07-02T13:12:06Z" Recipient="https://10.19.31.141:9443/sps/SimpleSAML/saml20/login" InResponseTo="FIMREQ_4ee0b1eb-014e-1f6b-987d-b8d22c8d5967"/>
  </saml:SubjectConfirmation>
</saml:Subject>
```

because

```
<saml:AttributeStatement>
  <saml:Attribute Name="uid" NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:basic">
    <saml:AttributeValue xsi:type="xs:string">test</saml:AttributeValue>
  </saml:Attribute>
</saml:AttributeStatement>
```

If someone can provide a magical transform I'd love it, but I think I need clues (tutorial?) to come up to speed on transformation inside namespaces.  Suggestions?

Comment: See if this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26085859/need-help-in-creating-xslt-i-do-have-source-and-target-xml/26086154#26086154

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, Michael.  Indeed, the issue of namespace was exactly as noted: because the SAML response began

```
  <samlp:Response xmlns:samlp="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol" xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion"
```

I had to include those namespaces in the converter.

The answer turned out to be relatively simple:

1. populate a variable by scanning the tree
2. Apply the identity transformation
3. Transform the one element from the preserved variable.

The solution is fairly short, so I'll paste it below as an example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0" xmlns:samlp="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol" xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes" />

  <xsl:variable name="uid">
    <xsl:value-of select="/samlp:Response/saml:Assertion/saml:AttributeStatement/saml:Attribute/saml:AttributeValue"/>
  </xsl:variable>

   <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template> 

  <xsl:template match="saml:NameID/text()">
    <xsl:value-of select="$uid"/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```